# How to add a column to all DataFrames inside a Panel (don't mind using a for loop)

Tags: pandas

I've tried the code below, but although the column is added, the panel axis doesn't update.
I'm using Python 2.7.3 and Pandas 0.12.0.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

p = pd.Panel(np.random.rand(2,4,3),
             items=range(2),
             major_axis=pd.date_range('2013/11/10',periods=4),
             minor_axis=map(lambda x: "col%d" % x, range(3)))

p[0]
                col0      col1      col2
2013-11-10  0.942665  0.449846  0.194914
2013-11-11  0.831268  0.031158  0.399326
2013-11-12  0.079028  0.580820  0.459432
2013-11-13  0.858297  0.746162  0.457021

p.minor_axis
Index([u'col0', u'col1', u'col2'], dtype=object)

p[0]['col99'] = 1

p[0]
                col0      col1      col2  col99
2013-11-10  0.163177  0.737629  0.784708      1
2013-11-11  0.269936  0.609961  0.997503      1
2013-11-12  0.873156  0.295626  0.533119      1
2013-11-13  0.824352  0.381446  0.613053      1

p.minor_axis
Index([u'col0', u'col1', u'col2'], dtype=object)
```

The same happens with this code:

```
p[0].insert(1, 'col99', p[0].col0)

p[0]
                col0     col99      col1      col2
2013-11-10  0.942665  0.942665  0.449846  0.194914
2013-11-11  0.831268  0.831268  0.031158  0.399326
2013-11-12  0.079028  0.079028  0.580820  0.459432
2013-11-13  0.858297  0.858297  0.746162  0.457021

p.minor_axis
Index([u'col0', u'col1', u'col2'], dtype=object)
```

Any ideas?

I think one option would be a command to add another minor_axis. Does this exists?

Thanks,

JM

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check this for a solution
[Extending a pandas panel frame along the minor axis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15364050/extending-a-pandas-panel-frame-along-the-minor-axis)

To accomplish your scenario, it would be

```
x = p.transpose(2,0,1)
x['col99'] = 1
p = x.transpose(1,2,0)

p
<class 'pandas.core.panel.Panel'>
Dimensions: 2 (items) x 4 (major_axis) x 4 (minor_axis)
Items axis: 0 to 1
Major_axis axis: 2013-11-10 00:00:00 to 2013-11-13 00:00:00
Minor_axis axis: col0 to col99
```

Comment: note in 0.13 (releasing shortly, 0.13rc1 is out), see here: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/whatsnew.html#indexing-api-changes. You can do this more directly.

Answer (score 2):

Here's what you can do in 0.13, see [here](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/whatsnew.html#indexing-api-changes)

```
In [46]: p = tm.makePanel()

In [47]: p
Out[47]: 
<class 'pandas.core.panel.Panel'>
Dimensions: 3 (items) x 30 (major_axis) x 4 (minor_axis)
Items axis: ItemA to ItemC
Major_axis axis: 2000-01-03 00:00:00 to 2000-02-11 00:00:00
Minor_axis axis: A to D

In [48]: p.loc[:,:,'E'] = 1.

In [49]: p
Out[49]: 
<class 'pandas.core.panel.Panel'>
Dimensions: 3 (items) x 30 (major_axis) x 5 (minor_axis)
Items axis: ItemA to ItemC
Major_axis axis: 2000-01-03 00:00:00 to 2000-02-11 00:00:00
Minor_axis axis: A to E

In [50]: p.iloc[:,1]
Out[50]: 
      ItemA     ItemB     ItemC
A  1.555882 -0.098853  0.614742
B  0.617073 -0.022505  0.813114
C -0.484013 -0.244592 -0.479105
D  0.525216 -0.803064 -2.317367
E  1.000000  1.000000  1.000000

[5 rows x 3 columns]
```